# Does the function $\log(1+\exp(x))$ have a conventional name?

Tags: functions, terminology

Does the function $\log(1+\exp(x))$ (or the function $\log(1+\exp(-x))$) have a conventional or at least fairly common name?

Alternatively, is it closely related to some reasonably well-known, named function?

[It arises in a problem I'm working on and it would be nice to use a reasonably standard terminology and notation rather than either writing $\log(1+\exp(g(x)))$ each time (where $g$ is a fairly complicated set of terms), or coming up with a non-standard notation for it (like $\omega(g(x))$ say) and then discovering I could have used a symbol and term for it that are already recognized). It would also help in terms of locating properties, should I end up needing any beyond the simple ones I've already derived.]

Comment: May I propose $\text{Glen_b}_\text{+}$ and $\text{Glen_b}_\text{-}$ ? Back to serious, I do not think that they have a name.

Comment: “As we shall be often using the following function, we shall write $\operatorname{wow}x=\log(1+\exp x)$”

Comment: @egreg yes, thanks, I had already written something rather like that, but I'd rather not dodge convention if I can find one.

Comment: This is the sigmoid function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Comment: @norbert No, it isn't, the sigmoid function is bounded above while this function is not. It is related to it - it's minus the log of the sigmoid function.

Comment: @Glen_b sorry, my bad

Comment: Last year, in a GLM course I took, we called $x \mapsto \log(1 + e^x)$ the "soft positive part" function since it's roughly $\max\{0,x\}$. A quick google search didn't reveal any references calling it, though.

Answer (score 9):

The name **softplus** has been coined in 2001 ([Dugas et al.](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/publications2/index.php/attachments/single/83)), and seems to be in fairly common use by now.